# Angular On Refresh Styles Are Not Applied (304 for all js and css files)

Tags: angularjs, iis-express, asp.net-core

I am creating a sample application using Asp.Net 5 with web Api anf angular js .I am using html files for my front end angular app . I have added Web.Config to wwwroot folder with url rewrite rule to handle hard page refresh . This rule always redirects the request to Index.html page and it's working fine . When I hit F5 it remains on the same page . But the problem is styles are not getting applied . For all .css and .js files I am getting 304 response(Not Modified) . I am not sure how to handle this . Below is the code for url re writing .

[image]

```
<configuration>

  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Angular" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll">
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsDirectory" negate="true" />
            <add input="{REQUEST_URI}" pattern="^/(api)" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Rewrite" url="/index.html" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration
```

Comment: I got it fixed by changing action type Rewrite to Redirect